# About k8s metrices server only some resources can be monitored

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

#### Version

1. k8s version: v1.19.0
2. metrics server: v0.3.6

I set up k8s cluster and metrics server, it can check nodes and pod on master node,
work node can not see, it return unknown.

```
NAME    CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
u-29    1160m        14%    37307Mi         58%
u-31    2755m        22%    51647Mi         80%
u-32    4661m        38%    32208Mi         50%
u-34    1514m        12%    41083Mi         63%
u-36    1570m        13%    40400Mi         62%
```

when the pod running on the client node, it return `unable to fetch pod metrics for pod default/nginx-7764dc5cf4-c2sbq: no metrics known for pod`
when the pod running one the master node, it can return cpu or memory

```
NAME                     CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
nginx-7cdd6c99b8-6pfg2   0m           2Mi
```

Comment: Is there any guide/documentation that you have followed while setting it up?

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer based on OP's comment posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

The issue was caused by using different versions of docker on different nodes. After upgrading docker to v19.3 on both nodes and executing `kubeadm reset` the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the metrics server receives the metrics via the kubelet.

Maybe there is a problem in retrieving the information from that.

You will need to look at the follow configurations mentioned in the [readme](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/master/README.md).

> Configuration
> Depending on your cluster setup, you may also need to change flags passed to the Metrics Server container. Most useful flags:
>
> --kubelet-preferred-address-types - The priority of node address types used when determining an address for connecting to a particular node (default [Hostname,InternalDNS,InternalIP,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP])
>
> --kubelet-insecure-tls - Do not verify the CA of serving certificates presented by Kubelets. For testing purposes only.
>
> --requestheader-client-ca-file - Specify a root certificate bundle for verifying client certificates on incoming requests.

Maybe you can check below configuration changes.

```
--kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP 
--kubelet-insecure-tls
```

You might be able to refer [this ticket](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/237) to get more information.

Comment: I fix this issue, because of different version on docker, some is 18.06,some is 19.3, after upgrade to 19.3,and kubeadm reset, it works for all pods, thx

Comment: @benq Consider posting the actions you have taken as an answer. It would be better visible for the rest of the community.